# CSS and display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I'm having some difficulty with. It looks similar to the content below. The behavior I'd like (if it's possible) is for the .content div to remain to the right of the image. As the page shrinks horizontally, the text should resize itself, but STILL REMAIN TO THE RIGHT OF THE IMAGE.

I'm not using a float left because it's important for this that the the text doesn't merely wrap under the image; they should stay to their respective sides. I feel like this is an elementary CSS issue but I haven't had any luck trying to find a solution.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            <!--
            body    {
                max-width: 900px;
                margin: 50 auto;
            }
            .callout.news   {
                vertical-align: text-top;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(167,167,167,.4);
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .callout.news img,
            .callout.news .content {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .callout.news img   {
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            .callout.news .content  {
                min-width: 200px;
                max-width: 600px;
            }
            -->
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="callout news">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/4ayWDo" />
        <div class="content">
            <h3>This would be a Header</h3>
            <p>Sed finibus semper ante, sit amet suscipit mauris tincidunt et. Curabitur eget nisi lorem. Pellentesque vel erat elit. Mauris vehicula leo leo, vel semper ante malesuada et. Aenean laoreet vulputate tristique. Morbi gravida sem at sapien auctor, quis pellentesque ante dignissim. Praesent iaculis sem eget ex feugiat, nec luctus nunc tempus.will focus on the societal impact of human services.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle for the lazy http://jsfiddle.net/tf2emzLb/

Comment: i think you are looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/tf2emzLb/1/

Comment: No, I'm not. I'll try to rephrase it above to make it clearer. I DO NOT WANT THE TEXT TO WRAP UNDERNEATH THE IMAGE UNTIL THE ENTIRE DIV MOVES THERE; I'd even be willing to never have it move there, and stay to the right of the image. The important thing here is that THE TEXT STAY TO THE RIGHT OF THE IMAGE, BUT STILL RESIZE ITSELF AS THE PAGE SHRINKS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width`

```
.callout.news {
vertical-align: text-top;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(167,167,167,.4);
padding: 10px;
min-width: 852px;/**add this*/
}
```

Full code

```css
body    {
                max-width: 900px;
                margin: 50 auto;
            }
            .callout.news   {
                vertical-align: text-top;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(167,167,167,.4);
                padding: 10px;
                min-width: 852px;/**add this*/
            }
            .callout.news img,
            .callout.news .content {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .callout.news img   {
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            .callout.news .content  {
                min-width: 200px;
                max-width: 600px;
            }
```

```html
<div class="callout news">
    <img src="http://goo.gl/4ayWDo" />
    <div class="content">
        <h3>This would be a Header</h3>
        <p>Sed finibus semper ante, sit amet suscipit mauris tincidunt et. Curabitur eget nisi lorem. Pellentesque vel erat elit. Mauris vehicula leo leo, vel semper ante malesuada et. Aenean laoreet vulputate tristique. Morbi gravida sem at sapien auctor, quis pellentesque ante dignissim. Praesent iaculis sem eget ex feugiat, nec luctus nunc tempus.will focus on the societal impact of human services.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like the text to collapse down, but still stay to the right of the image. This is just assuring the text never gets small enough to collapse down to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 50 auto;
}
.callout.news {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(167, 167, 167, .4);
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.news img,
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.news img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.callout.news .content {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout news">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://goo.gl/4ayWDo" />
    <h3>This would be a Header</h3>

    <p>Sed finibus semper ante, sit amet suscipit mauris tincidunt et. Curabitur eget nisi lorem. Pellentesque vel erat elit. Mauris vehicula leo leo, vel semper ante malesuada et. Aenean laoreet vulputate tristique. Morbi gravida sem at sapien auctor, quis
      pellentesque ante dignissim. Praesent iaculis sem eget ex feugiat, nec luctus nunc tempus.will focus on the societal impact of human services.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This uses a float, and if the text goes over, it spills under the floated image. I need the text to stay to the right of the image.